# Updating User Data node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I faced into a problem when testing my app: when testing on several accounts, it turned out that the data is added only to the description of the account on which the testing was carried out, even if another user is currently authorized at the moment. When I discovered this, I began to rewrite the code, but nothing happens, I don’t understand what’s wrong, it seems to me that I’m passing the wrong data to **user-controller.js** and **user-service.js**

**router.js**

```
router.put('/updateUser/:id', userController.update);
```

**controller.js**

```
class UserController {
 async updateUser(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const userUpdate = await userService.update(req);
            return res.json(userUpdate);
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**service.js**

```
class UserService {
 async updateUser(req) {
    const userUpdate = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      req.body.user,
      { new: true }
    );
    const userDto = new UserDto(userUpdate);
    return { user: userDto };
  }
}
```

**user-dto.js**

```
module.exports = class UserDto {
    email;
    id;
    description;

    constructor(model) {
        this.email = model.email;
        this.id = model._id;
        this.description = model.description
    }
}
```

**user-model.js**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  description: {
    city: { type: String },
    brand: { type: String },
  },
});
```

Comment: looks good.. check the code which is passing id to `router.put('/updateUser/:id'`, could be the wrong `id` or something... also, you might add more details what is the expected result and what is the problem